# Getting Segmentation Fault when passing pointer to pointer to a function

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, function-pointers

When passing "pointer to pointer" to a function getting segmentation fault.Code is generating Binary search tree through insert function.
Insert function is getting pointer to root node and a key value which it inserts at correct position

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
strong text
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;

};

void insert(struct node** node,int data)    
{
    if( *node == 0 )
    {
        (*node) = (struct node* ) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        (*node)->data = data;
        (*node)->left = 0;
        (*node)->right = 0; 
    }
    else if(data < ((*node) -> data)){      
        insert((&((*node) -> left)),data);
    }
    else if(data > ((*node)->data)){
        insert((&((*node)->right)),data);
    }
}

void inordertreversal(struct node* node)
{
    inordertreversal(node->left);
    cout << node->data;
    inordertreversal(node->right);
}

int main()
{
    struct node *root = 0;
    insert(&root,10);
    insert(&root,6);
    inordertreversal(root);

    return 0;
}
```

Help much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check next nodes everytime:

```
void inordertreversal(struct node* node)
{
    if (node->left)
        inordertreversal(node->left);

    cout << node->data;

    if (node->right)
        inordertreversal(node->right);  
}
```

After this:

```
$ g++ example.c -o example && ./example
6
10
```

Comment: And I would add
''if (node == 0) return;''
at the beginning

Comment: Thanks , din't analyse properly inorder